# Work Around or Fix for NPM lite-server on Linux error when running Angular 2 Quick Start

Tags: linux, npm, ubuntu-14.04, angular, lite-server

I am unable to start the lite-server 2.1.0 using npm on Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to run the Angular2 Quick Start example.

This problem may be specific to Linux and only started to occur after a recent update to Ubuntu. I am able to run the Angular2 Quick Start successfully on Windows 8.1. I have tried various different versions of NPM and Node with no changes in my results. Running the Angular Heroes example also fails with the same issue.

Any solution or temporary work around would be greatly appreciated.

After successfully transpiling typescript to javascript, here is the result of attempting to start lite-server via npm:

```
npm run lite

events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch node_modules/insight/node_modules/lodash/internal/baseForOwnRight.js ENOSPC
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1313:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1341:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/tf/sbtf/ang2-reg/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/tf/sbtf/ang2-reg/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/tf/sbtf/ang2-reg/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/tf/sbtf/ang2-reg/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/tf/sbtf/ang2-reg/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)

npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-49-generic
npm ERR! argv "/tf/node/bin/node" "/tf/node/bin/npm" "run" "lite"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ang2-reg@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Here's the package.json. I did upgrade lite-server to 2.1.0 to see if that would help, but it did not.

```
{
  "name": "ang2-reg",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "typings" : "typings"
  },
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.20",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.17",
    "zone.js": "0.5.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.0",
    "typings":"^0.6.8"
  }
}
```

Here's the typescript config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Here's the error message portion from the npm-debug.log:

```
10 verbose lifecycle ang2-reg@1.0.0~lite: CWD: /tf/sbtf/ang2-reg
11 silly lifecycle ang2-reg@1.0.0~lite: Args: [ '-c', 'lite-server' ]
12 silly lifecycle ang2-reg@1.0.0~lite: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle ang2-reg@1.0.0~lite: Failed to exec lite script
14 verbose stack Error: ang2-reg@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous>
 (/tf/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:239:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
 (/tf/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
 (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
15 verbose pkgid ang2-reg@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /tf/sbtf/ang2-reg
17 error Linux 3.19.0-49-generic
18 error argv "/tf/node/bin/node" "/tf/node/bin/npm" "run" "lite"
19 error node v5.6.0
20 error npm  v3.7.2
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error ang2-reg@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
22 error Exit status 1
```

Comment: I am able auto transpile with this command:  npm run tsc:w

Comment: This was caused by the dreaded ENOSPC error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same error and I can solve it in ubuntu with the next steps:

Edit the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add the next line:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

Save the file and type:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

And try again run npm start. :)

Comment: Works for me too. Thanks! I'm curios, why did this fix the problem?

Comment: This worked for me as well. In fact, it even worked when I specified 32K instead of 512K. However, the impact of using 512K is really just memory. The number appears to be based off this link: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers  There's probably nothing magical about the number itself.

Comment: Hint for Arch Linux users: Systemd only applies settings from /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf. If you had customized /etc/sysctl.conf, you need to rename it as /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf and do the work there!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a workaround the idea is to use the **version 4.x** of NodeJS.

Remove NodeJS 5.x

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

Edit the sources list to enable node 4.x in the repo

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```

Then in the file edit both two lines:

```
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x vivid main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x vivid main
```

To

```
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x vivid main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x vivid main
```

Update the repos again

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And reinstall node

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Check the versionm which should wrtite something like v4.3.1 or v4.x.x

```
node -v
```

Now you can run the angular quickstart with:

```
npm start
```

Hope it is useful.

EDIT:After installing the version 4.x of NodeJS

In the folder where you have your app:

```
$ rm -r node_modules
```

And then

```
npm install
```

Looks stupid, but when you run npm install it has to compile certain modules, and maybe (I do not know) the way of compiling them changes with the NodeJS versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I had previously tried this but tried it again to see if I missed something.  Same problems, slightly different line numbers from the "stack trace".

Comment: Seems obvious but, have you tried, after installing NodeJS v4.x, to remove the node_modules folder and install the modules again?